# Angular Flex-layout with Tabs layout

Tags: css, angular, tabs, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to align a Headline and Angular Tabs (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) in one row using Flex-Layout (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) but the content of the Tabs to be displayed over the whole screen. At the moment the content is only displayed under the Tabs (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX5CT.png)). I want the content to be displayed like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqDs6.png). So together I want the tabs to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX5CT.png) and the content to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqDs6.png).

This is the code in the component.html, which brings me [the first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX5CT.png).

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" >
<h2 class="title">Partner Summary</h2>
</div>
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab label="Overview"> <app-overview-partners></app-overview-partners></mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Table"></mat-tab>      
</mat-tab-group>
```

I'm thankful for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update, I found a solution that worked for me ([Angular Material Tabs how to customize tab row and add text or dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519190/angular-material-tabs-how-to-customize-tab-row-and-add-text-or-dropdown-list)). I just needed to make the position of the Headline to be absolute. Here is the html file:

```
<h2 class="title">Partner Summary</h2>

<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="end" animationDuration="0ms">
<mat-tab label="Overview">
    <app-overview-partners></app-overview-partners>
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Table">
    <app-table-partners></app-table-partners>
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and here the important css changes:

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 34px;
```

}